# FreeMarker support for AngularJS and embedding FTL in JSP

Tags: angularjs, jsp, freemarker

Can we embed `Freemarker Template` within `JSP` and vice versa?

Does `FreeMarker` support `AngularJS`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to include ftl in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003817/not-able-to-include-ftl-in-jsp)

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a purely client-side technology as far as I know, so what you are using on the server-side (JSP or FTL) is irrelevant.